# How can I set my JAR file class path to use an outside folder for dependencies?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, dependencies

I am making a java web application that a hosting service is running for me, and I must recompile and send it to the host every time I make a change. I would like to be able to put all of my libraries in a folder in the host, and only have to compile my jar that will know that its dependencies are next to it.

I have used the IntelliJ IDEA builder located in File > Project Structure. I export all library jars used in a folder next to the main jar named `lib`, and I have learned about wildcards so I set the classpath to be `\lib\*`. This did not work and I was thrown a chunky `NoClassDefFoundError` in my server's console.

I know this must be possible. How should I change my approach?

EDIT: I have researched a bit deeper, and the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/including-all-the-jars-in-a-directory-within-the-java-classpath) states at the bottom that the wildcard system is not honored in the jar manifest attribute. Do I have to include all files individually (And if so, how?) ?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/including-all-the-jars-in-a-directory-within-the-java-classpath

Comment: Yes, that's where I learned about wildcards. The answer explains it is better to do `*` rather than `*.jar`, and also described a known bug in 1.8 where there has to be a preceding slash in the classpath

Comment: @Ale Lav add command in your question which you have used.

Comment: @DhrumilPatel I'm not using any command to execute this. If you want higher clarification, I'm making a Minecraft server plugin that the server will take care to run for me, but the jar's dependencies are about 8MB, when the real jar is about 4KB, I could save so much time.